# Git config command showing permission denied

Tags: windows, git, permissions

I'm new to Git and repeatedly getting the following error.

When I type the command `git config --global color.ui auto` I get the error:

```
error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/.gitconfig: Permission denied
```

I have been getting the same permission denied error for other commands as well. I don't know if there is any problem with the path.

Comment: `git config --global` tries to update your per-user configuration, which should definitely *not* be in some jdk binary directory. (Where it should be, on Windows, I don't know, but that's clearly wrong.) Did you set `$HOME` to something weird?

Comment: HOME is set to the jdk bin directory. Later I installed git.

Answer (score 1):

`HOME` should not be set to the JDK bin folder, but to your `%USERPROFILE%`.

Do check in a CMD session the value of your account:

```
set USER
```

You should see your username and USERPROFILE folder.

Then try the same `git config` command, in that `CMD` session, setting `HOME` first:

```
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

Comment: I used the `set HOME` command but nothing happened. Git bash shows the same error.

Comment: Are you in a CMD session, or a git bash session?

Comment: For the question I was in Git bash but as you told to change HOME, I did it in CMD and `git config` is working in CMD but not in git bash.

Comment: `git config --global` is working but not the one mentioned in question. Clearly there is something wrong.

Comment: In a bash session, use export HOME=/c/Users/yourAccount

Answer (score 1):

I was facing permission denied for `git config --global user.name` command from Git bash in Windows.

I ran the Git bash with Administrator privileges and was able to resolve the error.

*Note: I also got the same error from Intellij trying to commit changes; that too got resolved after running Intellij in Admin mode.*

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, trying to set the initial configuration for git - `user.name` and `user.email` and failing with a "Permission denied" error. It failed in Normal and Administrator mode and on all CLIs - PowerShell, CMD and GitBash.

**The reason** in my case was rather stupid. Somehow I had a `~/.gitconfig` folder, rather than a file, so the CLIs were failing to create the file, due to filename conflict. Although the error message could have been more helpful.

**The solution** - just delete the folder and try again.